# Listing and Displaying of Users and Organization in Liferay 7

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I am trying to List all the **users** and **organizations** present in the db in liferay(7.1.2 ga3) on a JSP page.

I know i have to use **UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsers()** and **OrganizationLocalServiceUtil.getOrganizations()** inside render method to get the list of users and organizations.
then i have to use renderUrl(**which i don't know how to use**) in jsp to display the lists.

I can retrieve the list of organizations and print them in console but for users **nothing** is getting printed in console.

Can some one please tell how to retrieve the list of users, and then what to write in jsp file to display them(users and organizations).

Not asking for code just a small example or steps or some document for this process.

I'll add my code below to show how i am trying.

```
@Override
public void render(RenderRequest renderRequest, RenderResponse renderResponse) throws IOException, PortletException
{   
               //   for users (not getting printed in console)
    List<User> getUsers = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsers(QueryUtil.ALL_POS, QueryUtil.ALL_POS);
    renderRequest.setAttribute("users", getUsers);
    _log.info("Users:" + getUsers);
            
              //    for organizations   
    List<Organization> getOrganizations = OrganizationLocalServiceUtil.getOrganizations(QueryUtil.ALL_POS, QueryUtil.ALL_POS);
    renderRequest.setAttribute("organizations", getOrganizations);
    _log.info("Organizations:" + getOrganizations);
            
    super.render(renderRequest, renderResponse);
}
```

Comment: A question first: Are you aware that you're doing this in the "render" phase, which is typically triggered by an Ajax request (not just by rendering the portlet)? The way you phrase the question, I'd recommend to start with overriding `doView`, rather than `render` and go from there.

Comment: thanks !! for the input. I used render earlier for getting the prefix and suffix for the user registration and country list for adding organization because the list was already in the db. So, I thought can implement the same like here too. Will try like you said and update here.

Comment: The render usually redirect to a jsp example view.jsp in that jsp you with have the lists in the request attributes, just need to get them from the request

Comment: @RomeoSheshi I apologize for replying so late. Followed your advice and got what i wanted thanks !! for your valuable comment.

Comment: @OlafKock thanks !! for your suggestion but i went with render method, I tried the doView method also but couldn't implement it properly, will have to figure that method out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'll add how i tried and it's working as expected.

In my render method:

```
//  for retrieving users from "user_" table in db
            
List<User> getUsers = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUsers(QueryUtil.ALL_POS, QueryUtil.ALL_POS);
renderRequest.setAttribute("users", getUsers);
            
//  for retrieving organizations from "organization_" table in db
            
List<Organization> getOrganizations = OrganizationLocalServiceUtil.getOrganizations(QueryUtil.ALL_POS, QueryUtil.ALL_POS);
renderRequest.setAttribute("organizations", getOrganizations);
```

my listUser.jsp

```
<tbody>
    <c:forEach var = "listUsers" items = "${users}">
        <tr>
            <td> <c:out value = "${listUsers.firstName}"/> </td>
            <td> <c:out value = "${listUsers.middleName}"/> </td>
            <td> <c:out value = "${listUsers.lastName}"/> </td> 
            <td> <c:out value = "${listUsers.emailAddress}"/> </td>
            <td> <c:out value = "${listUsers.screenName}"/> </td>   
            <td> 
                <c:forEach var = "listContacts" items = "${contacts}">                  
                    <c:out value = "${listContacts.birthday}"/>  
                </c:forEach>                    
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

my listOrganization.jsp

```
<tbody>
    <c:forEach var = "listOrganizations" items = "${organizations}">
        <tr>
            <td> <c:out value = "${listOrganizations.name}"/> </td> 
        
<!-- For Comparing countryid in organization_ table and countryid in country table in db to display country name present in country table-->                
            <td>    
                <c:forEach var = "compareCountries" items = "${countries}"  >
                    <c:if test = "${listOrganizations.countryId eq compareCountries.countryId}">    
                        <c:out value = "${compareCountries.name}"/>     
                    </c:if> 
                </c:forEach>        
            </td> 
         </tr> 
    </c:forEach>                                                                     
 </tbody>
```